# how to use swagger annotations for dynamic resource in jersey

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0

I want to know is it possible to add swagger annotations to a jersey resource created dynamically via the jersey programmatic resource api

what i have so far

```
final Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder("message");
 
final Resource.Builder childResource = resourceBuilder.addChildResource("group");
childResource.addMethod("GET").handledBy(new GetInflector());
 
final Resource resource = resourceBuilder.build();
```

now where to add tha @Api annotation of swagger??

Comment: You can ..What you have tried so far?

Comment: You have to add `@Api` in class level or interface , basically starting point where your API hit.

Comment: @VinayHegde would you kindly elaborate. what i seem to gather from your response is that i should annotate the inflector class?

Comment: Are you using springfox ?

Comment: @VinayHegde no i am not using springfox or spring and as for resource this is how my resource is getting created i.e. programmatically when i run this i will have a resource which i can hit at localhost:8080/message/group

Comment: I prefer you use springfox , because how swagger works is it will scan all `@Api` resource and form a `swagger.json` then springfox will automatically load that and build html page , if we have not used springfox then might be you have to build your own html .

Comment: FYI: I see `swagger 2.0` as the question tag and `@Api` is from Swagger 1.x. If you're using Jersey 2, then go with Swagger 2.x. Swagger 1.x will bring in Jersey 1.x transitively which will create conflicts in classpath.

Comment: There is no way to use annotations with programmatic resources. The classes are introspected to find these annotations, and with programmatic resources, there are no classes to introspect. You would have to make a class with the annotations in place and use Resource.builder(resourceClass) method to make a resource. So it would be like half programmatic half declarative.